# A question about $L^p$ convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

I was thinking about this fact:

Let $X$ be a measure space and let $f_n : X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ a sequence of measurable functions in $L^p$ which converges a.e. to a function $f$ in $L^p$. Is it true that $f_n$ converges to $f$ in the $L^p$ norm with $p<\infty$?

I did the case $p\geq 1$. It works, basically my idea was to use triangle inequality and Minkowski inequality to prove that $(|f_n|+|f|)^p$ is summable. From $|f_n-f|^p\leq (|f_n|+|f|)^p$ and the dominated convergence theorem (generalized version) we finish.

But what about the case $p<$1?

Comment: If $X = \mathbb{R}$, and we take the Lebesgue measure, then $f_n = \chi_{[n,n+1]}$ converges to $0$ pointwise, but $\lVert f_n\rVert_p = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that $\int_{X} (2|f|)^p = lim \int (|f_n| + |f|)^p$